# How do I get Visual Studio to see my newly built library via nuget without deploying it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm very new to NuGet.

(Note that I am using Visual Studio 2015.)

Before we started to use NuGet, all our shared libraries (class libraries, DLLs) were brought into each project that needed them via SVN's "extern" feature.  Thus, from Visual Studio's point of view, all projects were part of the solution and one could make a change anywhere and do a rebuild and test to his/her heart's content.

Now the shared libraries are linked in via NuGet.  They are not part of the solution. When debugging, I can step into the library code by pointing the debugger to the source under the "packages" folder, but suppose I find something in there (down in the library) I want to change.  Now I want to test it with my application.  I'm not ready to deploy this change as a new version of the library -- I may want to make further changes after some tests, etc.

What I want is for things to be like they were before, where I could make some changes, rebuild, test, make more changes, etc.  I don't want to always have to deploy a new version of the library with every change.

Surely there's an easy way to do this.  With Java and Maven, there's the concept of a "local repository" and one can "install" a new version locally as many times as one wants before "deploying" it to the main repository.  Also, Eclipse makes debugging easy in that as long as you have all the projects open it will automagically use the newest code when building everything.

I'm hoping someone out there in StackOverflow land can make sense of these ramblings and help me out.

EDIT: I should add that I (we, my team) am the author of both the application and the library.  The library (in this case a general "utilities" library) is shared among several applications that we produce.  Our experience in Java with Maven and Eclipse is what led us to consider using NuGet to duplicate that environment in Visual Studio and C#.  We are very new to NuGet, so I apologize if this seems like a rookie question.

Answer (score 0):

Even though we could debug the NuGet packages with [Symbol Packages](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/symbol-packages), if we change some code for the NuGet source code, we still need to re-pack it to generate modified packages.

I suggest you reference the Nuget package source project into your project and then debug and modify them. After debugging, then pack them as packages and push to Nuget feed.